# All default unity objects are black?

Tags: unity-game-engine

This is the first time I've used Unity and I am trying to follow a basic tutorial on making a simple ball game. In the tutorial "[Roll-a-ball"](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/projects/roll-ball-tutorial), all of the objects appear white and you can see the shadows they make. I followed the tutorial completely, but everything I make shows up as black and I cannot differentiate the objects from each other. What is causing this and how can I fix it?

[image: Screen shot of tutorial (left) to my project (right)]

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific?  At least the tutorial you're following.  What version of unity3d are you using?

Comment: Yes, sorry. The Tutorial is called "Roll a Ball". And it is Unity5.4.0f3. Please let me know if you need something else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no ***camera*** added to your ***scene*** & also ***lighting***.
Add the **Main Camera** & **Directional Lighting**. It will do the trick.